# Sinatra asset pipeline, can't make it work

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am using Sprockets with Sinatra, as suggested in Sinatra's page docs, but I can't make it work.

When I go to `localhost:4567`, the page loads correctly but with no styles. If I go to `localhost:4567/assets/app.css`, I get a not found error. I wonder what I am missing or what is wrong in the way I am using Sprockets?

This is my folder structure:

```
├── assets
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── app.css
│   │   ├── base.css
│   │   └── normalize.css
├── bin
│   └── app
├── lib
│   ├── app_assets.rb
│   └── main.rb
├── spec
│   ├── spec_helper.rb
│   └── main_spec.rb
├── views
│   └── index.erb
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── Rakefile
├── .rspec
└── .ruby-version
```

The contents of `app.css` are:

```
//= require normalize
//= require base
```

The contents of `app_assets.rb` are:

```
module AppAssets

  def self.environment root_path
    environment = Sprockets::Environment.new root_path
    environment.append_path './assets/css/'
    environment

    # get assets
    get '/assets/*' do
      env['PATH_INFO'].sub!('/assets', '')
      settings.environment.call(env)
    end
  end

end
```

The contents of `lib/main.rb` are:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sprockets'
require 'app_assets'

class Main < Sinatra::Base

  set :views, "#{settings.root}/../views"

  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end

end
```

The file `views/index.erb` contains the line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/app.css">
```

And the contents of `bin/app` are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib')

require 'sinatra'
require 'sprockets'
require 'app_assets'

require 'main'
Main.run!
```

Which I run typing:

```
$ bin/app
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure I made something wrong but I can't see what. Can anybody spot it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `app_assets.rb` file is the problem here. When you require this file inside another file, the methods you define inside this module are not automatically included. You need to explicitly `include AppAssets` wherever you need the `self.environment` method to exist.

The second issue here is that `self.environment` is not equivalent to `settings.environment`. If I understand correctly, what you're trying to do is define the asset routing whenever the module gets included. To achieve this one way is to use the `included` hook for modules. This hook gets run every time you include a module inside a context. If you use that, the code in `app_assets.rb` turns to:

```
module AppAssets
  def self.included(klass)
    environment = Sprockets::Environment.new klass.settings.root

    # note the change to path. Since the file where this gets included
    # is inside a sub-folder, we need to traverse to one level above.
    environment.append_path '../assets/css/'
    klass.set :environment, environment

    klass.get '/assets/*' do
      env['PATH_INFO'].sub!('/assets', '')
      klass.settings.environment.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

The `klass` argument to this hook is the class into which this module is included. In our case this is the Sinatra class you've described in `main.rb`. That file looks like:

```
class Main < Sinatra::Base
  include AppAssets

  # Same as what you have
end
```

There's a Sinatra Recipes article about using Sprockets with Sinatra: http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/asset_management/sprockets?#article

Comment: Thank you! that solved the issue. I'm new to Sinatra and didn't know about the included method. I was following the link you posted, but wanted to have the assets in their own module so that I could reuse it in other classes.